# Past perfect tense - it means they had never tried...

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect

In below quote why past perfect tense has been used?

> "If someone feels that they had never made a mistake in their life, then it means they had never tried a new thing in their life."

We use Past perfect tense to tell or imagine past of past. But in the above quote, which are the two past?

Also are these below sentence constructions are correct?

If I want to say some one about the past, can I say:

> 1. I had called you.

If I want to say where I was when you called me:

> 2. I had gone to wash room.

Or the simply simple past will do?

Please clarify

Comment: Past Simple for the second part.

Comment: The sentence is ungrammatical.

Answer (score 2):

When talking about things in the **past**, the **past perfect** happens before the **simple past**.

In your example

> If someone **feels** that they **had never made** a mistake in their life, then it means they **had never tried** a new thing in their life.

**had never made** and **had never tried** are two actions which were started and ended in the **past** compared with how the person **feels** (present).  The equivalent would be

> If someone **feels** that they **never made** a mistake in their life, then it means they **had never tried** a new thing in their life.

where **never made** is nearer in time than **had never tried** since one would have had to try **before** failing.

> I **had called** you
>   I **had gone** to the wash room

could individually use the **simple past**

> I **called** you
>   I **went** to the wash room

with similar meaning, however, using **past perfect** sets up a scenario for something in the more recent past

> I **had** called you before I **went** to the wash room
>   I **had gone** to the wash room before I **called** you

To answer where you were when they called:

> I **had gone** to the wash room when you **called** me

means you were in the wash room *(past perfect)* when the person called

> I **went** to the wash room when you **called** me

means you heard the phone ring then went *(simple past)* to the wash room